# Records vs Tagged tuples in public api

Tags: erlang

Is it common practice to return records from query functions? If not, what are the downsides?

Let's say I have a query service, that can return some *cars* and whether they are currently rented or not.

My record for *car* looks something like this:

```
-type rent_state:: rented | available.
-record(car, {make::string(), year::integer(), color::string(), state::rent_state()}).
```

If I then had a query for cars, is it a reasonable thing to do to return this record?

```
-type car::#car{}.
-spec cars() -> [car()].
```

or should I create a tagged tuple type instead?

```
-type car()::{ {make, string()}, {year,integer()}, {color,string()}, {state,rent_state()}}).
```

I want to make an API that is pleasant to use for others. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using records locally to a module, but I find that sharing them between applications runs into a few warts:

- It's a little painful to get them loaded into the REPL
- Record definitions are global, so you'd probably want to name your record `drozzy_vehicles_car` or something else long and then using it would be ugly
- Users of your library have to include your header file that defines the record or it won't work

The tagged tuple you describe seems like a big pain to work with -- there's no easy way to grab something out of the middle.

I would use maps if you're lazy and accessors if you aren't.

Maps:

```
Car = #{ make => "foo", year => 2016, color => "red", state => rented}.
```

Accessors:

```
1> Car = rentals:get_car().
{car,"foo",2016,"red",rented}  %% it's actually a record, but we don't expose that!
2> rentals_car:year(Car).
2016
3> rentals_car:state(Car).
rented
4> % etc
```

Comment: Also. When adding data to your reply and upgrading the system while handling requests and using records you have to load the calling module first and make the new version of that module handle both the old (now a tagged tuple) and the new version of the record since you don't know which version for the query service module that was called.